# What algorithm does MATLAB use to find eigenvectors?

Tags: matlab, eigenvector

So I am using MATLAB for a project and am discussing the use of the power method for finding stationary distributions of Markov chains and its convergence rate. I was wondering what method/algorithms MATLAB's `eig()` function uses to find the eigenvectors of a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally Matlab is using LAPACK routines to do calculation. With that in mind I guess that from [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d4/d7a/group__eigen_g_e.html) you will be able to find the code that matlab runs. Be Aware LAPACK is in Fortran.

[MATLAB Incorporates LAPACK](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matlab-incorporates-lapack.html)